# Windows Defender is currently deactivated and controlled by a sys admin

Tags: windows-10

I wanted to uninstall my previous antivirus (Panda Free Antivirus) and switch back to Windows Defender. I now have uninstalled my previous AV, but i can't turn Windows Defender on.
[Here's the message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH9wJ.png)
(it roughly translates to the title of this question)
And in the security parameters :
[Same here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z84Zx.png)
(translates to "You use another antivirus provider")
I tried reinstalling and uninstalling my previous AV, this time using a program called revo uninstaller which scans for leftover after the regular uninstall, but the problem is still here.

I'm using Windows 10 Family with the Creator Update. (1703 15063.413)

Comment: Did you reboot after uninstalling?  I find that clears up a lot of issues.

Comment: Running more than one live A/V program concurrently can hang your computer.  Apparently, your system thinks the old one is still active.  I'm guessing that your version of Windows is not running in an enterprise environment.  That's off topic and may be where the pushback on your question is coming from.  The "sys admin" reference may indicate a permissions issue, that changing it requires elevated permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a machine used in corporate environment, and there *is* a sysadmin, then use the AV they provided.

However, if this is your *own* PC, the *sysadmin* comment likely means Panda used Windows Group Policy settings to disable Defender. To get it running again, if you have GPedit, then [MS describes the various settings, such as enabling real-time protection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/use-group-policy-windows-defender-antivirus). If you *do not* have GPedit, then run Regedit, and in [HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender delete the value *DisableAntiSpyware*](https://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/windows-defender-turned-off-by-group-policy) if it exists and try Windows Defender again.

[image: Defender Policies]